# jQuery animations in Flexbox - animation not running

Tags: jquery, animation, flexbox

I've created a grid of square divs using Flexbox to replicate a print image and want each square to slide down from the top of the highest container div when the page scrolls to a certain point. This isn't firing though I know the browser is getting the .scroll function because I have a console log running. I've been working to just get one div to slide at this point. Is Flexbox super strict or am I missing something? Here is the code.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $( this ).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
        $( "#small-twelve" ).slideDown( 5000, function(){
          console.log("scrolled!")
        })
        };
      });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="square-container">
            <div class="square-smalls-container">
              <div class="small-eleven">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>+63.5%</h3>
                  <p>more computer &amp; data processing <br/> services</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="small-twelve" id="small-twelve">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>+49.0%</h3>
                  <p>other freight &amp; <br/>port services</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
              <div class="long-one">
                <div class="text">
                  <h3>+247.9%</h3>
                  <p>more film &amp; television <br/>distribution services</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
.square-smalls-container{
        flex-direction: row;
        display: flex;
        flex: 2;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;
      }
.small-one, .small-two, .small-three, .small-four, .small-five, .small-six, .small-seven, .small-eight, .small-nine, .small-ten, .small-eleven, .small-twelve{
        display: flex;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
        flex-basis: 18%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
      }

.small-eleven, .small-twelve{
        flex: 1;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-right: 2%;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sliding one div by it's id

```
    $( "#small-twelve" ).slideDown( 5000, function(){
      console.log("scrolled!")
    })
```

Not sure why you expect others to move. Check your jQuery selector. This has nothing about flexbox :-)

Added class `slideMe` to some divs & updated your jQuery selector to select all divs with class `slideMe`:

```
 <div class="square-container">
        <div class="square-smalls-container">
          <div class="slideMe small-eleven">
            <div class="text">
              <h3>+63.5%</h3>
              <p>more computer &amp; data processing <br/> services</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slideMe small-twelve" id="small-twelve">
            <div class="text">
              <h3>+49.0%</h3>
              <p>other freight &amp; <br/>port services</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="slideMe long-one">
            <div class="text">
              <h3>+247.9%</h3>
              <p>more film &amp; television <br/>distribution services</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

And JS:

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $( this ).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50){
        $( ".slideMe" ).slideDown( 5000, function(){
          console.log("scrolled!")
        })
        };
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I was just trying to get one to move for now - once I got this working, I wanted to time other divs to slide at different rates for a varying effect. I added .slideMe to the classes and it didn't work still. :(

Comment: Yes - I used all your above code exactly as you provided.

Comment: So I might have an idea - when I use built in method .slideUp, the div slides up and disappears. Is it because the div is already visible that it isn't sliding down? How would you hide it for the function to make it appear upon scrolling?

Comment: Couple ways. 1. hide it with CSS on initial load 2. Hide with JS call .hide() just after the load.